# Stuck in wait() for thread execution to return

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, deadlock

I'm trying to write a thread that I can delegate testing and evolution of a robot to while I sort the existing chromosomes by fitness in the main thread. Below is the initial fitness method. What I want to do here is to have each genome tested by a robotHandler as the tests are 30 - 40 seconds long. I will only be running one of these threads at any given time.

Currently I seem to get caught in the wait() section of the intialFitness method. This is my first attempt at multithreading so any help as to how to debug the problem or if someone can spot the issue that would be fantastic

The RobotInterface class is just a testing class at the moment, I have commented out the log4j and sleep declarations to try and rule these out (Incidentally log4j was not logging anything in the thread if that helps)

```
public synchronized ArrayList<Genome> initialFitness( ArrayList<Genome> population)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < population.size(); i++  )
    {
        candidateTest = new CandidateTest(population.get(i));
        Thread robotHandler = new Thread(new RobotInterface( candidateTest));
        while(! (candidateTest.finishedYet() ))
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                logger.debug("The initialFitness method was interrupted, this shouldn't happen");
            }
        }
        population.set(i, candidateTest.getCandidate());
    }
    return population;
}

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import java.util.Random;
```

The RobotInterface Class

```
public class RobotInterface implements Runnable
{
// create a serial connection
// transmit a string and check for response
// wait for evaluation
// take evaluation
private CandidateTest candidate;
private Random rng = new Random();

//protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

public RobotInterface(CandidateTest test)
{
    this.candidate = test;
    //PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
}

public void evaluate (Genome genome)
{
    //send to robot and return fitness
    genome.setFitness(rng.nextDouble());
    //logger.debug("fitness is " + genome.getFitness());
    try
    {
        //logger.debug("Thread sleeping for 4 seconds");
        //Thread.sleep(4000);
    }
    catch(Exception E)
    {

    }

}

public void run() 
{
    //logger.debug("entering run of Robot Interface");
    //logger.debug("Send Genome via serial and wait for a response");
    Genome testSubject = candidate.getCandidate(); 
    evaluate(testSubject);
    candidate.finished();
    notifyAll();
}
```

}

The CandidateTest Class

```
public class CandidateTest
{
private volatile Genome candidate;
private volatile boolean testFinished = false;

public CandidateTest(Genome g)
{
    candidate = g;
}

public synchronized Genome getCandidate()
{
    return candidate;
}

public synchronized void finished()
{
    testFinished = true;
}

public synchronized boolean finishedYet()
{
    return testFinished;
}
```

}

Comment: I think you either need/mean to use Thread.sleep(<time>) or use an observer pattern (properly) whereby the wait object gets notified that the CandidateTest has finished.

Comment: I think you might have just answered the question, I forgot the damn thread.run didn't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are not starting the `robotHandler` thread.  So your main thread gets to `wait()` and then no other thread ever comes along to notify it.

Second, you call `wait()` on whatever class `initialFitness` belongs to, but you call `notifyAll()` on `RobotInterface`.  So `RobotInterface` will notify everyone who is waiting on it (nobody) and your main code will continue to wait.  You need to call `notifyAll()` on the same object on which you called `wait()`.

I suggest

```
synchronized(candidateTest) {
   candidateTest.wait();
}
```

and

```
   candidateTest.notify();
```

Comment: Sorry I think I've been looking at code for too long. Are you suggesting that I make the candidateTest the runnable in this situation?

Comment: Yes, I really was looking at it for far too long, I completely blanked on synchronized(){} vs synchronized methodName(). Thank you for all your help, modifying the candidateTest.wait() and moving notifyAll() into the finished method of CandidateTest has resolved the issue. Again thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Never seen where the Thread is started. Try:

```
 Thread robotHandler = new Thread(new RobotInterface( candidateTest)).start();
```

so your notifyAll() is never called

Answer (score 0):

Nathanial hit the nail on the head but I would suggest using the java.util.concurrent package if you are just getting started with concurrency in Java. Found a nice beginners article on DZone for you: http://java.dzone.com/articles/lazy-developers-introduction